# Rails: How to configure the logger for the Rails Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, actionmailer

I would like to set up the logger option of the Rails Action Mailer, but the only info I found are these lines over at [ruby on rails guides Action Mailer Configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration)

> logger: Generates information on the mailing run if available. Can be
> set to nil for no logging. Compatible with both Ruby's own Logger and
> Log4r loggers.

It should be `config.action_mailer.logger = :true`, but nothing happens. I also would like to log into a specific file such as for example mailer.log and not into the production.log. Does anyone have more info about how to get this done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That property accepts an object that meets the standard Ruby Logger interface, so for your needs (writing to a separate file) you might try something like:

```
config.action_mailer.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("mailer.log")
```

Comment: BufferedLogger is long deprecated. Use: Logger instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Robert' answer, BufferedLogger has been deprecated for a long time. Use Logger instead. Also, I recommend that you include the log/ folder in the file name, and place the log alongside your other logs.

```
config.action_mailer.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/mailer.log")
```